EntityManager is not injected and it's null when upgrading from jdk 8 to jdk 21 on Liberty server
I had an application that run fine on jdk 8 and Liberty 22.0.0.10. I'm upgrading my application to jdk 21 on a Liberty 24.0.0.9, and changed the pom.xml and some features in the server. The application starts, and REST endpoints and jms queue work, but when the database is called, it gets a null pointer because the entity manager em is not injected (with jdk8 it's properly injected and not null). Giving this error:
    nliberty.opentracing.internal.OpentracingJaxRsEMCallbackImpl W CWMOT0009W: The OpenTracing exception mapper detected and is handling an unhandled exception from the JAX-RS application.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class, Object)" because "this.em" is null

I'm using jpa-2.2 library, and from here seems like the jdk 21 is supported. These are the most relevant part of my pom (I upgraded some library from the jdk8 version):
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.extension</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>microProfile-4.0</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.0.9</version>
        <type>esa</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.jsf-2.2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-2.2</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.0.9</version>
        <type>esa</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>beanValidation-2.0</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.0.9</version>
        <type>esa</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>mpContextPropagation-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.0.9</version>
        <type>esa</type>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArguments>--add-modules=javax.annotation</compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>                            <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor
                            </processor>
                        </processors>
                        <outputDirectory>${build.java.generated}</outputDirectory>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            -Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/local/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${build.java.generated}</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>

This are my features on liberty server (I upgraded some library from the jdk8 version):
<server>    
  <featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
    <feature>microProfile-3.3</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-2.0</feature>
    <feature>mpContextPropagation-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
    <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>
    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature> 
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbPersistentTimer-3.2</feature>                                        
  </featureManager>    
</server>

I tried to use jakarta instead of javax but with no success (it broken my jms queue too), any idea about how to fix this null pointer?
Edit:
@Jared: I already had javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3, just omitted it from the pom so it didn't look too long.
This is the real error:
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:804 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo                        E CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the primary persistence unit in the ws-asd-forniture.war module and the ws-asd-forniture application.
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:805 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding               E CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:862 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl 201" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.22.0.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:862 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:885 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.inject 248" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.22.1.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:917 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl 118" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.22.2.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:22:917 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:033 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo                        E CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the primary persistence unit in the ws-asd-forniture.war module and the ws-asd-forniture application.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:034 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding               E CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:072 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl 201" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.23.0.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:072 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:089 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.inject 248" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.23.1.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:123 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl 118" at ffdc_24.09.24_16.12.23.2.log
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:124 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:134 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.opentracing.OpentracingJaxRsEMCallbackImpl        W CWMOT0009W: The OpenTracing exception mapper detected and is handling an unhandled exception from the JAX-RS application. 
                                                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class, Object)" because "this.em" is null
    at it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.dao.GenericDao.getItemById(GenericDao.java:29)
[others errors...]

[24/09/24, 16:12:23:253 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo                        E CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the primary persistence unit in the ws-asd-forniture.war module and the ws-asd-forniture application.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:254 CEST] 00000051 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding               E CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:255 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:256 CEST] 00000051 bm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl E CWOWB1000E: A CDI error has occurred: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-asd-forniture.war module of the ws-asd-forniture application cannot be resolved.

[this is another part the application, that if it finds out an error, it try to write it in a database row}
[24/09/24, 16:12:23:553 CEST] 00000051 ei.nuovaasd.terzeparti.ws.server.filter.RequestLoggingFilter E Errore durante le operazioni di tracciamento su LOG_CHIAMATA: Cannot invoke "javax.transaction.UserTransaction.begin()" because "this.userTran" is null

This is the first ffdc incident:
Exception = java.security.PrivilegedActionException
Source = com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl
probeid = 118
Stack Dump = java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/it.jajei.nuovaimu.terzeparti.ws.factory.FactoryResources/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the ws-imu-forniture.war module of the ws-imu-forniture application cannot be resolved.
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:575)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.callInject(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.injectJavaEEResources(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:319)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:694)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.getReceiver(AbstractMemberProducer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:694)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:345)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:356)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:69)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl$3.run(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl$3.run(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:322)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.injection.WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(WebSphereInjectionServicesImpl.java:322)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
[...omitted]

This is part of the class, the word "primary" match with my persistance.xml:
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Slf4j
    public class GenericDao {
    
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
        private EntityManager em;
    
        @Resource
        UserTransaction userTran;
    
        public <T> T getItemById(Class<T> clazz, Object id) {
            return em.find(clazz, id);
        }
}


<compilerArguments>--add-modules=javax.annotation</compilerArguments> looks a bit suspicious to me.  I would expect to use the dependency javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3 instead.  Some of your dependencies do not have a scope of provided where they are provided by liberty so that might be something to consider as well.
It would help to provide some details about what the code looks like for where the EntityManager is not getting injected.  Also are there any other warning / errors in the messages.log besides the one that you provided?
Starting in Java 11 some of the Java EE APIs were removed from the JDK and need to be provided by liberty features where they didn't require it previously.  It is possible your code needs one of those, but based off of what you provided above I am guessing not, but I could be wrong.

If the server fails to inject a resource, there should be an error indicating why and the application should fail to start. Since this application starts, but the field is just not injected, this means the server process is not aware injection is needed. A common cause is the annotation class is packaged with the application, like javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.  Liberty already provides this API class; it should not be packaged with the application.  Liberty detects this scenario and logs a CWNEN0070W message to indicate injection will not occur. Remove the API from the application.

I edited the original post with additional info. @Tracy I don't have the dependency javax.persistence.PersistenceContext. I set to provided all the openliberty dependencies, but the problem persist.

Based on the updates, the server recognizes the @PersistenceContext, but the JPA feature did not find the primary persistence unit. I would recommend looking to see that JPA started properly; there should be a message like
CWWJP9990I: [eclipselink] EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.15.v20240516-53511fdbd8, and also a message that the application containing the persistence unit started.  May need to enable JPA=all tracing and open a support case to determine why JPA is not locating the persistence unit.

Is your pom.xml accurate in the original post because it is showing the cdi and validation dependencies not listed as provided.  It would be good to look at your WEB-INF/lib directory where you are putting dependent jars in your application to see if there are javax prefixed jar files in the application.
